# Django как в url передать параметр из контекста шаблона?

Tags: python, django

Шаблон:

```
<form action="{% url 'new_item' category=category %}" method="post">
```

Урлы:

```
url(r'^new/(?P<category>[\w\-]+)/$', views.new_item, name='new_item'),
```

Представление:

```
def new_item(req, category=''):
args = dict()
args.update(csrf(req))
if req.method == 'POST':
    if category == 'phone':
        form = PhoneForm(req.POST, req.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('general')
        else:
            args['form'] = form
            return render_to_response('new_item/index.html', args)
else:
    if category == 'phone':
        args['form'] = PhoneForm()
        args['category'] = 'phone'
return render_to_response('new_item/index.html', args)
```

Причём для обычной ссылки подобный код срабатывает, а для form нет

```
<a href="{% url 'new_item' category=category %}"></a>
```

Ошибка:

> NoReverseMatch at /adminpanel/new/phone/ Reverse for 'new_item' with
>   arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'category': ''}' not found. 1
>   pattern(s) tried: ['adminpanel/new/(?P[\w\-]+)/$']

Answer (score 2):

В первой части ты не передаёшь в шаблон переменную category. И соответственно url не получает аргумента, поэтому и ошибка.

Код не проверял, но скорее всего так.
Попробуй:

```
def new_item(req, category=''):
    args = dict()
    args.update(csrf(req))
    if req.method == 'POST':
        if category == 'phone':
        form = PhoneForm(req.POST, req.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('general')
            else:
                args['form'] = form
                args['category'] = 'phone'
                return render_to_response('new_item/index.html', args)
    else:
        if category == 'phone':
            args['form'] = PhoneForm()
            args['category'] = 'phone'
    return render_to_response('new_item/index.html', args
```

)